# How to style Ionic controls on composite backgrounds

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile web app using Ionic Framework currently.

This app is using a background image or a svg gradient.

When I display controls like the checkbox and the toggle control, the controls shows inside a big white box...

Do you guys have a much nicer way of styling this?

See my codepen:

http://codepen.io/flemmingdjensen/pen/bEjMwZ

CSS:

```
.scroll-content {
  background: url('http://www.yosemitepark.com/Images/Fall_Medow_M-1.jpg');
}
```

HTML / IONIC CODE:

```
<div class="list list-inset">
  <ion-toggle>Toggle Control</ion-toggle>
  <ion-checkbox>Checkbox Control</ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to be adding alpha to the background of .list and .item like

CSS:

```
.list, .item {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #fff;
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

See the codepen